# Why does this program not follow the rules of matrices?

Tags: arrays, matrix

I have the following code and cannot prove the theorems on AB != BA and onward to number 8. I tried multiplying matrices using online calculators and yielded the same result my program gave me.

```
Matrix a = new Matrix(new int[][]{{1,2},{4,3}});
Matrix b = new Matrix(new int[][]{{3,2},{4,5}});
Matrix c = new Matrix(new int[][]{{2,2},{-1,-1}});

System.out.print("1. (A^T)^T=A \t\t = ");
System.out.println(a.transpose().transpose().equals(a));

System.out.print("2. (A+B)^T = A^T+B^T     = ");
Matrix added = a.add(b).transpose();
System.out.println(added.equals(a.transpose().add(b.transpose())));

System.out.print("3. (2A)^T = 2A^T \t = ");
System.out.println(a.scalarMult(2).transpose().equals(a.transpose().scalarMult(2)));

System.out.print("4. (AB)^T = B^T A^T \t = ");
Matrix mult = a.transpose().mult(b.transpose());
System.out.println(mult.equals(a.mult(b).transpose()));


System.out.println("5. AB != BA  \t\t = " + a.mult(b).equals(b.mult(a))); //though some cases AB != BA, this case they are equal? 
//I tried 2 different calculators for matricies online and got the same results


System.out.println("6. A(BC) = (AB)C \t = " + b.mult(c).mult(a).equals(a.mult(b).mult(c)));

System.out.println("7. A(B+C) = AB + AC =    = " + (a.add(b)).mult(c).equals( (a.mult(c)).mult(b.mult(c))));

System.out.println("8. (2A)B = 2(AB) = A(2B) = " + (a.add(b).mult(c).equals(a.mult(b).add(b.mult(c)))));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5. It is NOT true that AB and BA will ALWAYS yield different results. The rule is that matrix multiplication is noncommutative, but it's not exclusively noncommutative, meaning that while in some cases, like in your program, A*B and B*A yield the same result, it is not always the case. And it's usually not, you just happen to have sample matrices that do that.
6. The rule says "A(BC) = (AB)C" which is the associative property of matrix multiplication. But the code you have essentially does "BCA = ABC". Because matrix multiplication is not commutative, you need put "A" to the left of "(BC)" like so: `a.mult(b.mult(c))`

   > ```
   > a.mult(b.mult(c)).equals((a.mult(b)).mult(c))
   > ```
7. The rule says "A(B+C) = AB + AC" which is the distributive property. Your code does "(A+B)C = (AC)(BC)". This needs to be slightly rewritten.
8. The rule says "(2A)B = 2(AB) = A(2B)". Your code does "(A+B)C = AB + BC". This code is unrelated to this rule and just looks like number 7.